# Topology of singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

In the theory of surface singularities, it is well known that the topology of singularities is determined by its resolution dual graph.
What`s the meaning of the topology of singularities?
Here the topology is the same as the topological space?

Comment: Probably the equivalence class of the germ of the singularity by homeomorphisms.